# Selecting Joints in hierarchy one at a time

Tags: python, maya

I have this code

```
joint_name = cmds.ls(sl=1)[0]
circle_name = cmds.circle(name = joint_name + "_CTL", nr=(1, 0, 0) )
group_name = cmds.group(name = joint_name + "_OFFSET")
cmds.select(joint_name, group_name)temp_constraint = cmds.parentConstraint()
cmds.delete(temp_constraint)
cmds.select(circle_name, joint_name)
cmds.pointConstraint()
cmds.orientConstraint()
```

When you select a joint and run this code you will get a circle that will control that joint. While going down the hierarchy you have to select that joint and then run the code.

How would I be able to have all the joints to have circles controlling them without having to go through the outliner selection a joint?

Comment: cmds.ls(sl=1, dag=1, type='joint') to parse every joint under selection so you can just do a for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run this on your chain of joint :

```
for x, joint_name in enumerate(cmds.ls(sl=1, dag=True, type='joint')):
    circle_name = cmds.circle(name = '{}_CTL{:02d}'.format(joint_name,x), nr=(1, 0, 0) )
    group_name = cmds.group(name = '{}_OFFSET{:02d}'.format(joint_name,x))
    cmds.select(joint_name, group_name)
    temp_constraint = cmds.parentConstraint()
    cmds.delete(temp_constraint)
    cmds.select(circle_name, joint_name)
    cmds.pointConstraint()
    cmds.orientConstraint()
```

Note that instead of use select, you could feed pointConstraint :
cmds.pointConstraint(circle_name, joint_name, n='something')